# Compress buffer in hapijs and send to client

Tags: gzip, protocol-buffers, content-type, zlib, hapi.js

I have a huge JSON object. (can have array of up to 100 objects)
The smallest size it has is about 8kb. Largest can go up to 2 mb.

If I send it as JSON with `response.type("application/json")` it is of size **8kb**;

```
response.type("application/json");
response.content = getJSONData();
```

To resolve this, I created a buffer using [protobufjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs).
If I encode it using protobufjs, and send it as `octet-stream`, it is of size **93kb**

```
response.type("application/octet-stream");
response.content = myProtoBufSchema.encode(content).finish();
```

And response is in the string form `{"type":"Buffer","data":[10,36,51,48,53....]`

If I add `response.variety = "buffer";` to above code, it sends it as a buffer object that I convert on client side using the following, the size reduces to **27kb**

```
var buffer = new Uint8Array(xhr.response);
var response = parseProtobuf(buffer);
```

The `content-encoding: gzip` is only available when I send it as a JSON.

But it does not get added when I am sending it as a buffer.

If I add `response.header("Content-Encoding", "gzip");` the size reduces to **600Bytes**, but I get the error on browser, `err_content_decoding_failed`, because it didn't actually compress but header said content-encoding was gzip.

So is there anything that I can change, or how do I use [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) in hapi to compress my buffer (not JSON).